# Der Sache kann gerecht geworden werden?

Tags: future

Wenn Etwas in der Zukunft einer Sache gerecht werden kann, dann ...

> ... kann der Sache gerecht geworden werden?

Da *einer Sache gerecht sein* so nicht verwendet wird, ist *gerecht werden* scheinbar schon passiv. Gefragt wird nach eine Form von *Er wird der Sache gerecht (werden)* ohne *Er* (und zur Erhöhung des Schwierigkeitsgrades im Futur 1 oder 2).

Das soll sachlich, objektiv wirken und ist typisch z. B. in juristischen oder technischen Texten. Eben daher kommt vermutlich dieser Ausdruck. Die fragliche Formulierung klingt aber gestelzt.

Comment: Haha, ich gönne diese Frage denen, die Spaß an sowas haben. :)

Comment: Ich kann hier beim besten Willen kein Passiv sehen. *Einer Sache gerecht werden* ist kein bißchen anders als *grün werden*.

Comment: @tofro, doch, die Vorsilbe *ge-* deutet auf Partizip hin, wie beim passiv.

Comment: Das Partizip wird nicht nur fürs Passiv verwendet, sondern für viele andere Bildungen auch. Unter anderem fürs Futur II, "ich werde *ge*gangen sein" ist kein bißchen Passiv.

Comment: @tofron, *gegangen werden* ist analog zu *bewegt werden* doch logisch. Was nicht logisch ist, ist eine rekurisve Konstruktion wie *sich bewegen*, die bei *gehen* fehlt, welches deshalb nicht transitiv zu sein scheint und daher keinen passiv hätte. *sich bewegen* ist redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Die von dir vorgeschlagene Formulierung wirkt nicht nur gestelzt, sie ist auch grammatikalisch falsch. Außerdem handelt es sich keineswegs um eine Passivkonstruktion.

---

### Die Verben »sein« und »werden« sind nicht dasselbe

Ich kann dieses Argument nicht nachvollziehen:

> Da einer Sache *gerecht sein* so nicht verwendet wird, ist *gerecht werden* scheinbar schon passiv.

Nö.
*»Sein«* und *»werden«* sind doch nicht zwei Formen desselben Verbs, sondern zwei verschiedene Verben. Das eine (sein) drückt aus, dass sich etwas gerade in einem bestimmten Zustand befindet, während das andere (werden) ausdrückt, dass etwas gerade dabei ist, seinen Zustand zu ändern.

Beispiele:

- Präsens

  > sein: **Ich bin krank.** = Ich befinde mich jetzt in einem unerfreulichen Zustand.
  >   werden: **Ich werde krank.** = Ich mache jetzt gerade (in der Gegenwart) einen Zustandswechsel durch.
- Präteritum

  > sein: **Ich war krank.**
  >   werden: **Ich wurde krank.**
- Perfekt

  > sein: **Ich bin krank gewesen.**
  >   werden: **Ich bin krank geworden.**
- Plusquamperfekt

  > sein: **Ich war bereits krank gewesen** als ich Ilse traf. (Als ich Ilse traf war ich schon wieder gesund.)
  >   werden: **Ich war bereits krank geworden** als ich Ilse traf. (Als ich Ilse traf war ich krank.)
- Futur I

  > sein: **Ich werde krank sein.**
  >   werden: **Ich werde krank werden.**

  Beachte, dass das zweite Wort im Satz (*werde*) nur ein Hilfsverb ist, das aus grammatischen Gründen notwendig ist, um die Zeitform Futur I zu bilden. Diese Hilfsverb trägt keine semantische Information, es ist lediglich ein grammatischer Marker. Das Vollverb, um das es geht, steht am Ende des Satzes.
- Futur II

  > sein: Jetzt bin ich noch gesund, aber bis zu deinem Geburtstag **werde ich krank gewesen sein.** (Und an deinem Geburtstag werde ich auch wieder gesund sein.)
  >
  > werden: Jetzt bin ich noch gesund, aber bis zu deinem Geburtstag **werde ich krank geworden sein.** (Und werde auch an deinem Geburtstag noch krank sein.)

---

### Das Vollverb »werden« kann nicht im Passiv verwendet werden.

Nicht alle Verben sind in der Lage einen Passiv zu bilden.

Versuchen wir, aus einem bereits vorhandenen Passivsatz einen Aktivsatz zu machen:

Aus jedem Passivsatz lässt sich ein Aktivsatz erzeugen, indem man das Subjekt des Passivsatzes zum Akkusativobjekt des Aktivsatzes macht. Gleichzeitig wird das eventuell vorhandene Präpositionalobjekt des Passivsatzes zum Subjekt des Aktivsatzes. Wenn es kein solches Präpositionalobjekt gibt, muss man sich für den Aktivsatz ein plausibles Subjekt ausdenken:

**Mit Präpositionalobjekt:**

- Passiv

  > Der Hund wird von Heinrich gestreichelt.
  >   Von Heinrich wird der Hund gestreichelt.

  **der Hund** = Subjekt
  **wird gestreichelt** = Prädikat
  **von Heinrich** = Präpositionalobjekt
- Aktiv

  > Den Hund streichelt Heinrich.
  >   Heinrich streichelt den Hund.

  **den Hund** = Akkusativobjekt
  **streichelt** = Prädikat
  **Heinrich** = Subjekt

**Ohne Präpositionalobjekt:**

- Passiv

  > Der Hund wird gestreichelt.
  >   Gestreichelt wird der Hund.

  **der Hund** = Subjekt
  **wird gestreichelt** = Prädikat
- Aktiv

  > Den Hund streichelt *jemand*.
  >   *Jemand* streichelt den Hund.

  **den Hund** = Akkusativobjekt
  **streichelt** = Prädikat
  **jemand** = Subjekt, das im Passivsatz nicht explizit als Präpositionalobjekt vorhanden war.

Für den umgekehrten Weg (*mache aus einem Aktivsatz einen Passivsatz*) folgt daraus **ZWINGEND**, dass in Aktivsatz an das Verb ein Akkusativobjekt gebunden sein muss. Dieses Akkusativobjekt wird nämlich zum Subjekt des Passivsatzes, und dieses Subjekt muss vorhanden sein.

Also kann man nur mit transitiven Verben Passivsätze bilden. Wenn ein Verb gar kein Akkusativobjekt haben kann, kann man damit keinen Passivsatz bilden:

Beispiele für Sätze, die man nicht als Passivsatz formulieren kann:

- Intransitive Verben

  > Ich schlafe.
  >   Die Sonne geht unter.
  >   Du wartest auf den Bus.
  >   Eugen hilft Verena.
- Reflexive Verben

  > Hans wäscht sich.
  >   Ich freue mich.
  >   Willi bedankt sich bei Ursula.

Das Vollverb »werden« ist ein intransitives Verb. Daher kann man damit keine Passivsätze bilden. Der Satz

> Etwas wird einer Sache gerecht.

Ist ein Aktivsatz, den man nicht in einem Passivsatz umwandeln kann.

---

### Flexionen von »einer Sache gerecht werden«

- Präsens

  > Etwas wird (jetzt) einer Sache gerecht.
- Präteritum

  > Etwas wurde (gestern) einer Sache gerecht. (Und ist es heute noch.)
- Perfekt

  > Etwas ist (gestern) einer Sache gerecht geworden. (Ist es heute aber nicht mehr.)
- Plusquamperfekt

  > Etwas war (vor einem anderen Ereignis, das in der Vergangenheit stattfand) einer Sache gerecht geworden.
- Futur I

  > Etwas wird (nächstes Jahr) einer Sache gerecht werden.
- Futur II

  > Etwas wird (bei Eintreten eines anderen zukünftigen Ereignisses) einer Sache gerecht geworden sein.

Answer (score 1):

Futur I bildet man mit "werden" und Infinitiv, also

> Er wird der Sache gerecht werden

Futur II bildet man mit dem Partizip und Hilfsverb - Aber niemals mit "werden", höchstens im Passiv.

> Er wird der Sache gerecht geworden sein.

Was du zu bauen versuchst, ist anscheinend eine Passivform, mir ist aber nicht klar, was das bedeuten soll.

"Einer Sache gerecht" ist eine attributive *Eigenschaft* eines Substantivs, eine *Adjektivphrase* - Also genau wie "grün" oder "doof". Was dabei ein Passiv soll, leuchtet mir nicht ein. Man kann auch nicht sagen

> <s>Er wird grün geworden werden</s>

Ich halte dein Beispiel also für schlichtweg falsch.

Im Übrigen halte ich deine These, dass "einer Sache gerecht sein" *so nicht verwendet* würde, auch für nicht besonders haltbar. Ich behaupte das Gegenteil.

> Der Lösungsansatz ist der Sache (des Problems) gerecht.

erscheint mir zwar geschraubt und eher ungebräuchlich, aber vollkommen richtig. Das läßt sich nachvollziehen, wenn man die Phrase rein adjektivisch verwendet:

> ein der Sache gerechter Lösungsansatz

Comment: OK, kann man so stehen lassen, ich würde aber *"ein der Sache gerecht werdender ..."* sagen, um das Idiom zu erhalten. Also werde ich das Idiom einfach vermeiden.

Answer (score -1):

*Es kann der Sache gerecht geworden werden* ist ein Grenzfall. Man könnte es grammatikalisch für möglich halten, allerdings ist es auf jeden Fall vom Stil her grauenhaft. Die Bedeutung ist dieselbe wie "Man kann der Sache gerecht werden". Vergleiche "Es kann gegangen werden" / "Man kann gehen".

Das Passiv will hier nicht so richtig funktionieren, weil *werden* kein transitives Verb ist (es kann kein Akkusativobjekt haben). Allerdings ist das nicht zwingend erforderlich, wie man am Beispiel mit "gehen" sehen kann, das ebenfalls kein transitives Verb ist.

Achtung: Es muss unterschieden werden zwischen "werden" als Hilfsverb (im Passiv) und als Vollverb. In "einer Sache gerecht werden" ist "werden" ein Vollverb. Wenn daraus ein Vorgangspassiv oder ein Futur gebildet wird, tritt "werden" einmal als Vollverb und einmal als Hilfsverb auf.

Comment: 1. »Es kann der Sache gerecht geworden werden« ist kein Grenzfall, sondern schlichtweg falsch. 2. Bitte bilde einen Passivsatz mit »gehen«.

Comment: Habe ich bereits: "Es kann gegangen werden"

Comment: Oder einfacher: "Es wird gegangen." (Subjektloses Passiv)

Comment: Ich gebe zu, dass »Es kann der Sache gerecht geworden werden« sich einfach falsch anhört. Es ist aber nicht so leicht zu sagen, woran das liegt, denn das Deutsche erlaubt es, auch intransitive Verben ins Passiv zu setzen. Bei "werden" widerspricht das aber dem Sprachgefühl.

Comment: Der Hauptgrund, warum sich das falsch anhört, dürfte sein, dass es falsch *ist*. Bilde das Passiv von "ich werde alt" - Genau dasselbe versuchst du mit "ich werde gerecht".

Comment: Diese Verwendung von *Es* ist gar noch viel grauenhafter. Umgangssprachlich geht das alles, auf dem Niveau hatte ich die Frage auch gestellt, aber Ziel war reines Hochdeutsch.

Comment: Passiv von "alt werden" wäre "Es wird alt geworden". Hört sich natürlich auch verkehrt an. Wahrscheinlich muss man *werden* einer Gruppe von Verben zuschlagen, bei denen das Passiv schlicht nicht funktioniert. "Sein" gehört offenbar auch dazu.